# Xamarin xml android:onClick callback method

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

This is my XML code:

```
    <Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/MyButton"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:onClick="sayHellow" /> //RELEVANT PART
```

And this is my main activity:

```
[Activity(Label = "FFFF", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light")]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    }
    public void sayHellow(View v) //CALLBACK FUNCTION
    {
        Snackbar.Make(v, "My text", Snackbar.LengthLong)
            .Show();
    }
}
```

Problem is I get a runtime error and the debug window complains that `Button`could not find "sayHellow" function, but as you can see I declared everything according to the docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must export the method:

```
[Export("sayHellow")]
public void sayHellow(View v)
{
    Snackbar.Make(v, "My text", Snackbar.LengthLong).Show();
}
```

And you must add the reference to the `Java.Interop.dll`

[image]

---

A simpler solution would be:

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

button.Click += delegate {
    //Clicked
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had to use `Java.Interop.Export` after I referenced `Mono.Android.Export.dll` but you're right, it's working.
You helped me so much today I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, i've said that in my answer and added a screenshot for it.