# How to use One imageview variable that refer to multiple imagesViews in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Im trying to create a simple Connect 3 game in Xamarin it has 9 ImageView, I created this Connect 3 in Android Studio using Java. In Android Studio i can import View.view at the begining and use that view to ImageView and refer to any imageView within the application without using FindingViewById Function. Like this.

```
public void dropIn(View view){
count= 0;
ImageView image = (ImageView)view; // You dont have to use FindViewby ID this referes to every imageView which is used.
        if (count == 0) { 
        image.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.yellow);
            count = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            image.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.red);
            count = 0;
        }
```

My Queston: Is there any to implement the same thing in Xamarin

```
count=0
ImageView image = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1) //there are 9 Images like imageView2,imageView3 and etc till imageView9
image.Click += delegate
        {
            if (count == 0) { 
            image.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.yellow);
                count = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                image.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.red);
                count = 0;
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin xml android:onClick callback method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800931/xamarin-xml-androidonclick-callback-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the same Click Event handler for all your ImageView's.

The `EventArgs` for the Event fired on Clicked, does contain the sender, which would be the ImageView responsible for the click:

```
void ImageClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var image = (ImageView)sender;
    // do stuff to the image...
}
```

Then just hook it up to your images:

```
image1.Click += ImageClicked;
image2.Click += ImageClicked;
```

Or you could export a similar `dropIn` method:

```
[Export("dropIn")]
public void DropIn(View view)
{
    var image = (ImageView)view;
    // do stuff
}
```

You need to make sure to Export it so Android can find it from the native side.

Then you can use it in your XML/AXML as usual:

```
<ImageView
    android:onClick="dropIn"
```

To get this to work properly you probably need to add a reference to Mono.Android.Export